# Laravel Relationship between 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

so I am trying to get the category name and this is what I have
tablets:

> **categories**: id,name
>
> **post_categories**:  id,  post_id,  category_id
>
> **post** :  id,  columns

I have the models: `Post`, `PostCategory` and `Category`.

Post Model :

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PostCategory');
}
```

PostCategory Model :

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'id', 'category_id');
}
```

and in the controller I have

```
return Post::with('categories.category')->orderby('id','desc')->get();
```

And my result is

```
 [
  {
    "id": 50,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 92,
        "category_id": 11,
        "category": [
          {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "JXrfLHdQVNON",
            "image": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i wanted it to be something like

```
[
  {
    "id": 50,
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category_name",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do it? I have been playing around with this and havent manage to find a easy way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your Post model :

```
 public function categories()
 {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Category','post_categories','post_id','category_id')->withTimestamps();
 }
```

in your controller :

```
return Post::with('categories:id,name,image')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: Yes!!! that was the relationship I was looking for thank you very much you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship. Make sure you have your relationship set up correctly. If you want to choose specific columns you can do:

```
return Post::with('categories.category:id,name')->orderby('id','desc')->get();
```

It will return the columns `id, name` from category table/ model. You must specify `id` doing that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: this returns an array called "category" inside the array "categories" my idea was to display the category name inside each categories array element